# Add a dimension to a multidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

```
byte[,] matrix;
```

and i want copy in a 3 dimension array

```
byte[,,] 3dplan;
```

in this way

```
3dplan[,,0]=matrix
```

What is the fastest way to accomplish this task in c#?

Comment: This is so easy in Fortran, yet `C` based languages have not caught up to the simplicity of array operators and slice indeces. You always have to do the math by hand, one-by-one each component. Oh, how I long for an array aware .NET language with intellisense.

Answer (score 6):

You need to manually copy the elements in a nested loop; there is no faster way.

If you switch to a jagged array (`byte[,][]` or `byte[][][]`), you can insert the smaller array as-is into a slot in the larger array (although they will both refer to the same array instance and will pick up changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy 2d array into 3d array with Buffer.BlockCopy:

```
var _3dplan = new int[2, 2, 2];
var _2dplan = new int[2, 2] { { 1, 1 }, { 1, 1 } };
var index = 0;
var size = _2dplan.Length * sizeof(int);
Buffer.BlockCopy(_2dplan, 0, _3dplan, index * size, size);
```